# Pass string array as data in jquery ajax to web api

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass string array to a Web Api method which accepts an array of strings as argument. Bellow my Web Api method

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string HireRocco(string[] hitList)
    {
        string updateList = string.Empty;
        return updateList;
    }
```

My ajax

```
var uri = 'http://localhost:16629/api/AssassinApi/HireRocco',
hitList = ['me', 'yourself'];

$.ajax({
    url: uri,
    type: 'GET',
    data: { hitList : hitList },
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (data) {
    }
});
```

The above ajax successfully hits the `HireRocco` method but `hitList` param is still null. What should I change to pass an array of strings as param.

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar: its a GET method, anyway if I make a POST it won't resolve the problem

Answer (score 4):

If you need to send data via a `HttpGet`, you can add `[FromUri]` you can edit your controller action as follows and your JavaScript should work as is:

```
[HttpGet]
public string HireRocco([FromUri] string[] hitList)
{
    string updateList = string.Empty;
    return updateList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `contentType: false` then set `processData` to true so it can append the postData your url, as that's how a get request works or you will have to change your api to accept POST request which are set through the header.

```
$.ajax({
    url: uri,
    type: 'GET',
    data: { hitList : hitList },
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    processData: true,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all i suggest that you use POST rather than GET.
create a javascript array. push the data inside it. send it to web api action method by using JSON.Stringify.. and then process the further logic.

In web api create a model variable.. and create a list object..

Following is the code..

Javascript

```
var demoarray=[];
demoarray.push({"test1":"hi", "test2":"hello"}); //test1 and test2 are model variable names in web api and hi and hello are their values
```

you can repeat the process in for loop or something for adding multiple values.

```
 $.ajax({
      url:"http://localhost..",
      type: "POST",
      data: JSON.Stringify(demoarray),
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function(data)
               {
               },
      error: function(data)
             {
             }
       });
```

WEB API Code
Create a model class and two properties

```
public string test1 {get; set;}
public string test2 {get; set;}
```

controller code

```
[Httppost]
public void actionmethod(List<modelclass> obj)
{
  int i=0;
  for(i=0; i<obj.count; i++)
  {
    //your logic
  }
}
```